# Authentication, Authorization And Accounting? (PAM, RADIUS - again)

Tags: security

What are the advantages of RADIUS compared to PAM?

Comment: I think the question of how PAM feels about her RADIUS is a little too personal for this forum. Seriously though, please elaborate on your question. It's hard to answer in this form, I think.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [SO 4151544](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151544/authentication-authorization-and-accounting-pam-radius).

Comment: This question should have been asked as part of the related question.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two different types of system - these days, you normally access RADIUS through a PAM module ([FreeRADIUS PAM Module](http://freeradius.org/pam_radius_auth/)).  RADIUS is an authentication system; PAM is a framework that unifies different authentication systems.